# Target frame via name attribute

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, frameset

I am working on an old app that uses 3 frames. One of the frames has a "name" attribute

I am trying to target it via css like this but it's not working.

HTML

```
<frame name="classFrame" src="test2_files/overview-summary.htm"></frame>
```

CSS

```
 frame[name=classFrame] body{ font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe

Comment: I can't add any new stylesheets or js, just have to work with whats there, I was thinking i could target it using css3 somehow like in my above example

Comment: then this answer is probably what you'd want to do: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6100053/222714 (uses JavaScript to add a `<style>` block to the iframe)

Comment: Can you please provide a small example which demonstrates the problem?  Also, how do the other answers mentioned in the comments work (or not work) for you?

Comment: the other answers talk about including other stylesheets and JS which is not possible. I need to add the specificity via css 3 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot target a frame's contents from a frameset using CSS selectors.